# Convert image from readAsDataURL to readAsBinaryString

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

Using the [filereader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) it is possible to show a preview of the file, by reading the file with [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsDataURL%28%29)

What I am trying to do is:

1. The user selects a file
2. A preview is shown, so that the user has some feedback.
3. If the user is satisfied, he submits the data to the backend.

Implementing step 3 can be done by re-reading the file with [readAsBinaryString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsBinaryString%28%29), but this looks problematic because the data could have disappeared or changed on disk. So What I would like is to convert the data returned from `readAsDataURL` to the format returned by `readAsBinaryString`. How can I do this?

Another alternative would be to submit the data to the backend as returned by `readAsDataURL`, but I would like to avoid that, since that would require special handling on the backend in my case.

Comment: Why would the image on disk disappear or change?

Comment: Because somebody has changed or deleted it? Between the moment when the pre-view is generated and the moment when the data is sent to the backend, anything from 0 to a million million years can go by. In that time, lots of things can happen.

Comment: _“because the data could have disappeared or changed on disk”_ – and how likely is that in real-world conditions? That would either mean the user changed the file willingly, or some programm did it in the background … IMHO both not really likely scenarios (and the first one even kinda ridiculous, because the user _wants_ to upload what he saw in the preview). IMHO you are investing time here in a “problem” that deserves actually close to none.

Comment: @CBroe: I understand what you mean. I must confess the real reason I am investing time on this is not because I am worried about what happens on disk (that was just a fake reason to make me look professional), but because I *thought* converting from one format to another would actually be **easier** than re-reading the file, like `var binaryData = blahblah(urlData);` Of course, if it is soooo difficult to convert from `readAsDataURL` to `readAsBinaryString`, I might as well re-read the file as binary. I was not aware I was walking uncharted territory here.

Comment: Well, `readAsDataURL` will return a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) – if you strip the beginning  `data:[<MIME-type>]` part and the used encoding from that, and reverse the encoding that was used (base64 if `;base64,` is present, standard `%xx` hex URL encoding otherwise), you should have the same binary data as `readAsBinaryString` would get you. Also I doubt this will perform better than just reading the data again using `readAsBinaryString` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Like [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) said, you dont need to read the file twice.

JS :

```
 handleFileSelectThumbFile(evt){
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var file = files[0];

    // You can get the mime type like this.
    var thumbMIME = files[0]['name'].split('.').pop();
    if (files && file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {

        // Split the readerEvt.target.result by a ','. 
        // You can send the binaryString variable to the server. 
        // Its base64 encoded already.
        var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result.split(',')[1];

        // Set the image preview to the uploaded image.
        $('.img-preview').prop('src', readerEvt.target.result);
      }.bind(this);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```

HTML :

```
  <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileSelectThumbFile} required/>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/300' class='img-preview'/>
```

You can read the MIME type from the first part of readerEvt as well. Look at [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe)'s comment above.